# proving that for any vectors $u,v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ prove $\|u+v+w\| \leq \|u\| +\|v\|+\|w\|$ (verify)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-verification

for any vectors $u,v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ prove $\|u+v+w\| \leq \|u\| +\|v\|+\|w\|$

I wasn't sure how to go about this correctly so what I did was set $v+w$ to $v$, yielding $w = v-v = 0$, since it says for any vectors $u,v,w$. It seems like this method was used in the shorter version, but I'm not sure if that's really allowed. Is this legal, if so why or why not? It'd help my understanding of vector proofs. And if I'm not allowed to do that, would multiplying and expanding the values as they are somehow come out to a valid proof, possibly using the two vector C. Schwarz theorem?

Comment: Since you are trying to prove this for any vectors $u,v,w\in \mathbb{R}^n$, you do not want to pick specific vectors to start your proof. If you do, it won't prove the proposition in the general case, only proves in the case of w=0. I think you will have success with this if you expand in terms of inner product definition of squared norms. The suggestions below seem promising...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using triangle inequality two times:

$$\|u+v+w\| = \|(u+v)+w\| \leq \|u+v\|+\|w\| \leq \|u\|+\|v\|+\|w\|$$

Comment: I'm with you untill the last <= sign, I see how u made u+v a vector and applied the triangle theorem, but how did you use it again to show its <= to ||u|| + ||v|| + ||w|| ?

Comment: It's triange inequality aplied for $u,v$: $\|u+v\| \leq \|u\|+\|v\|$, if you add $\|w\|$ to both sides you get inequality with last sign $\leq$.

Comment: oh I see now. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not allowed to make a special choice of $w=0$. When it says 'for any $v,w$', it does not mean that you can choose any $v,w$ and prove it for those values. Quite the opposite, it means that your proof must be correct even if someone gives you the weirdest $v,w$ possible.

Cauchy Schwarz is one way to prove the triangle inequality which can be used to prove your result (see agha's answer), so in a sense, yes.